# Is it possible to use webkit css masks with SVG without an external file?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, svg

Webkit allows the use of an external SVG file as a mask for any HTML element. Ie:

```
<img src="kate.png" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(circle.svg)">
```

Resulting in:

[image]

(More information here: http://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/)

Does anyone know if there's a way to do it without an external SVG file? More specifically, can it be done with SVG generated from javascript?

Comment: It seems quite likely that this could be done using a data URI. If you link to a live demo, I'd be happy to test it. Also, when you say "SVG generated from JavaScript" do you mean in-browser, or out of the browser?

Comment: In-browser. For example using the Raphael library or plain document.createElementNS(). I'm not sure data URIs will work, but I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, two years have passed since I asked this question and the browser landscape changed a lot. Here's an example of exactly what I wanted to do, which works only in Firefox for now: http://mozilla.seanmartell.com/persona/

As you can see there's a div with id `chameleon` which has the following style:

```
<div id="chameleon" style="clip-path:url(#clip1); -webkit-mask-box-image: url(mask.png);">
```

`#clip1` points to a `clipPath` element inside an inline SVG element which links to a shape.

```
<clipPath id="clip1"><use xlink:href="#shape1"/></clipPath>
```

So now it's doable in Firefox.

Thanks [@mart3ll](https://twitter.com/mart3ll) for the practical example!

Comment: It works in Chrome and Safari too. Unfortunately IE11 is a no no.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the WebKit specific extension but Mozilla allow you to apply SVG effects like masks and filters on HTML elements. These can be defined in external files or directly in the markup. See [this post](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2008/06/applying_svg_ef.html). This isn't in any spec at the moment, but the SVG and CSS working groups are working together to spec this approach. See the [Working Group's page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/fx/charter/#scope) (although only filters, not masks are mentioned explicitly there).

You can usually link to something in SVG by including the id of the element in the url value (e.g. url(#someID)). You could try generating the SVG via JS, giving it an id and inject it into the document and see if it works. There is no spec as it is a WebKit extension so it is hard to say without trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe it's possible. Recently I used PHP to generate the SVG file.
Here is an example that I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/brokeneye/ygsKm/

Also check out http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: This is certainly interesting, but I think the question is asking if it can be done with SVG inside HTML, rather than standalone SVG.